# TwoWay Binding Using Initial Value From Source

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'd like to set up a binding in XAML that updates from either the source or target like a TwoWay binding. But when the DataContext is applied, I'd like the initial value to be taken from the Target like a OneWayToSource binding.

`<TextBox Text="{Binding Memo}" />`

How do I set up this binding so that the TextBox Text is updated from the Memo property of the DataContext, and vice-versa, but that the initial value on hookup is taken from the TextBox text?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't assign a value to the `Memo` property. By default the value of `TextBox.Text` is `null`.

You can set the `Binding.TargetNullValue` to set a default value:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Memo, TargetNullValue=TextBox default unset value}" />
```

Comment: Good answer, but TextBox is not the only control I want to use here. I'd like to use this on  the text field of DatePicker to prevent the DatePicker from taking a null string from the ViewModel bound to Text and applying it to the DateTime Value. That's a framework specific example, so I left it out of the question.

Comment: I think you have a few options here. You could set `Binding.TargetNullValue` on the binding of the `DatePicker` too, to set a default. You could set the value of the binding source, the view model property, to a reasonable non-null value e.g. `string.Empty`. So both controls `DatePicker` and `TextBox` would fetch a non-null initialization value. I don't know how the `DatePicker` will handle a `string.Empty` value.

Comment: You could use a `IValueConverter` to convert the string from the `TextBox` (or the bound view model string property) to a valid `DaterPicker` value e.g. `DateTime`, also giving you the chance to handle special (input) values like `null` or empty strings or white spaces e.g. by converting them to `DateTime.Now` (which could be a very reasonable default value for a `DatePicker`).

Comment: Setting any static value on the DatePicker Text property causes it to set the Value field with that date. If you set the Text to null or any valid value it'll actually change the date set for the DatePicker. We want the value to fall back to the property's current value. This works with OneWayToSource, but a TwoWay binding is needed here (TwoWayToSource would be perfect, but isn't supported).

Comment: I see. Then the only solution would be to implement a `IValueConverter` and assign it to the `Binding.Converter` property of the `DatePicker` <--> view model binding. Here you have full control over the value that is assigned to the target. If the value is not valid per your definition, you simply return `Binding.DoNothing` from the converter. This would discard the new but invalid binding value e.g. `null` and your `DatePicker` would keep the current value. No changes to the binding target. I hope I got you right.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the best solution for my particular use case. For the general question the answer looks like it's going to be "you can't". Thanks.